# Python: Moving a list to a row in Excel and appending using openpyxl

Tags: python, append, openpyxl

I tried to append a row containing a list to an Excel spreadsheet and received the following error:
**ValueError: Cannot convert [0.894, 0.566, 0.483, 0.27, 0.266, 0.268, 0.269, 0.161, 0.16, 0.157, 0.269, 0.284, 0.272, 0.261, 0.252, 0.227, 0.22, 0.222, 0.225, 0.239, 0.251, 0.257, 0.302, 0.292, 0.272, 0.272, 0.256, 0.224, 0.334] to Excel**
I fixed the code by referencing each list element separately as follows. This works but the code is very clunky. Is there a better way to do it (I'm new to Python)?

```
new_row = [' ', sa_length, pln[0], pln[1], pln[2], pln[3], pln[4], pln[5], pln[6], pln[7], pln[8], pln[9], pln[10],
pln[11], pln[12], pln[13], pln[14], pln[15], pln[16], pln[17], pln[18], pln[19], pln[20],
pln[21], pln[22], pln[23], pln[24], pln[25], pln[26], pln[27], pln[28],
pln_max, rect[0], rect[1], rect[2], rect[3],
edge1[0], edge1[1], edge1[2], edge1[3], edge1[4], edge1[5], edge1[6],
middle[0], middle[1], middle[2], middle[3], middle[4], middle[5], middle[6], 
edge2[0], edge2[1], edge2[2], edge2[3], edge2[4], edge2[5], edge2[6]]

#add a new row to the output excel file
ws_out.append(new_row)
```

Code successfully appends the row to the existing Excel file

Comment: What works and doesn't in your code isn't very clear; that said, you could create new_row in a simpler way: `new_row = [' ', sa_length, *pln[:29], pln_max, *rect[:4], *edge1[:7], *middle[:7], *edge2[:7]]` for example

Comment: Please include the code that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, Swifty. I just saw your response. Yes that's exactly what I did and it works

Answer (score 0):

#### To return all the lists on the same line.

#### Using * to unpack the lists worked for me:

```
new_row = [' ', sa_length, *pln, pln_max, *rect, *edge1, *middle, *edge2]
```

#add a new row to the output Excel file
ws_out.append(new_row)